# How to update state with an array via NGRX reducer in Angular?

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-reducers

I want to update my state using a ngrx reducer but I'm getting an compilation error.

For context. The user submits a worklog on a form, and I want this worklog to be added to the worklogs array on the state.

Here is the structure of my state:

```
export declare interface Outreach {
  outreach: CaseState|null;
}

export declare interface CaseState {
  outreachCaseId: string;
  worklogs: WorklogCase[];  // <- I want to add the new worklog here
}

export declare interface WorklogCase {
  worklogId: string;
  username: string;
  details: string;
}
```

The reducer:

```
const initialState: OutreachState = {
  outreach: null,
}

export const outreachDetailsReducers = createReducer<OutreachState>(
    initialState,
    on(outreachActions.addWoklogSuccess,
    state, {worklog}) => ({...state, worklogs: [...worklog]})),
```

I think I have the sintax wrong some how on the last line of the reducer. Any help?

Comment: can you share that syntax error msg here?

Answer (score 1):

You have your `worklogs` state nested under an `outreach` property that could be `null`.

Therefore, you will have to check that the `outreach` property is not `null` before updating its `worklogs` array with the new `worklog`:

```js
export const outreachDetailsReducers = createReducer<OutreachState>(
  initialState,
  on(
    outreachActions.addWoklogSuccess,
    state, { worklog }) => ({
      ...state,
      outreach: state.outreach !== null
        ? {
            ...state.outreach,
            worklogs: [...state.outreach.worklogs, worklog]
          }
        : null,
      }
  )
),
```

Ideally you should try to make your state as flat as possible to avoid the complexities that come with nesting.

Comment: This is the correct answer - but you can also take a look at ngrx-immer to make it easier to update state. https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-immer